# Log last N lines with irssi in real time

Tags: logs, irc, irssi

I am very new to irssi (and IRC in general), and I have the need to log only the last N number of lines from irssi to a text file, but I can't find any information on how to do something like that - be it with built in features or a script.

What I want to do is overlay the last 10 or so lines of chat on a video in real time. To do this I can use and ffmpeg filter which updates when a text file is changed on disk. Therefore what I want to do is continuously write the most recent 10 lines from an active irssi session to a text file.

How could I do that?

Comment: Is the problem getting the log or is it getting 10 lines only? If the latter,meould parsing the file to keep only 10 lines be acceptable?

Comment: I think logging the chat is easy enough with irssi, but I want only 10 lines in a text file because I'll be using ffmpeg to read said file and overlay it on a video in real time, so I need there to be at most 10 or so lines. I think it would be ideal to have irssi just put 10 lines in a file rather than have a script sitting there and continuously taking 10 lines out of the full log.

Answer (score 1):

If you run the output of `irssi` to the `tail` command you can get the last X number of lines, ex. `cmd | tail -10`.

#### Example

Using the `seq` command as a stand in for your `irssi` command. The `seq` command will generate a sequence of numbers from 1-100, in the example below.

```
$ seq 100 | tail -10
91
92
93
94
95
96
97
98
99
100
```

To dump it to a file, `/var/log/mychat.log`, you can redirect the output from `tail` using `>`.

```
$ seq 100 | tail -10 > afile
$ more afile 
91
92
93
94
95
96
97
98
99
100
```

If you'd like to see the output while writing it to the log file, you can use the `tee` command instead of the file redirect, `>`.

```
$ seq 100 | tail -10 | tee afile
91
92
93
94
95
96
97
98
99
100
```

Comment: Your last example describes basically what I want, however when I run `irssi | tail -10 | tee test.txt`, nothing happens. The terminal hangs and irssi never appears.

Comment: @CameronBall - I don't think you can do that with `irssi`, it would need to be writing to a log file and you could run the above against that log file.

Comment: See  the logging section for away in the docs: http://www.irssi.org/documentation/startup#c8. They show how you can log when you're away to a file, you could then tail that log file.

Comment: That's not really what I want to do. I need to get the last 10 or so lines from irssi in a text file which ffmpeg is reading to overlay on a video. So it needs to be continuously updated.

Comment: @CameronBall - perhaps you can update your Q then, since you're not giving us really enough to go on here. Try and be as thorough about what you're trying to accomplish.

Comment: Updated with a bit more info.